# EventEmitter inside custom module throwing '.on(...) is not a function'

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, eventemitter

I want to emit events from my Nodejs module but it's not working as expected as we are getting an error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Test.on(...) is not a function`.

Here is the module `test.js`

```
var util         = require("util");
var EventEmitter = require("events").EventEmitter;

function Test() {
  EventEmitter.call(this);
}

Test.prototype.test = function (input) {
  this.emit("testevent", input);
};

util.inherits(Test, EventEmitter);

module.exports = Test;
```

And in the `index.js` we have the following:

```
const Test = new (require('./test.js'));
Test.on('testevent', function (test) {
  console.log('emitted', test);
});
// Test.test('input');
```

I understand with just that code in `index.js` the event should never get emitted since `Test.test('input');` is not called.

However, with that line disabled, I am confused about why I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: Test.on(...) is not a function`.

The error goes away once `Test.test('input');` is uncommented and the event appears to emit as I can see the logged line. But why? Why is it throwing that error if the line is disabled? What are we doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Using `const Test = new (require('test.js'));` you are require `test.js` module from `node_modules` and there is one because you don't have MODULE_NOT_FOUND error, but is this a file you really want to require, or maybe this should be local file with realative path `const Test = new (require('./test.js'));`

After uncommenting this line `Test.test('input');` this is unlikely to log anything because this code emits `test` event and your code is listening for `testevent` only.

In general this code works well, here is a example https://repl.it/repls/DiscreteUnwrittenNet

Comment: Oops those are typos. I edited the question to reflect but we are in fact requiring a relative path `./test.js` and the event name is also a typo. It should read `testevent`. With those changes, does that make a difference?

Comment: As you can see in the example on the repl.it there is no problem with this code, if you still have problems, please give info about your environment, like node version, os.